# Linux thin station

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, drivers

I have this pc that I just installed and set it up as  Linux thin station. I did all the formatting procedures and copying of image to the HD. When I boot it up, I get these, which I think are driver messages, appearing on screen.

```
Thinstation init script

Loading modules:
...............................................................
.............................................................
....................................

Initializing rc0 packages...
profile_setup -  secure - pcmia - network - 

Configuring and starting network...
DHCP server not found! Network now initialize.
This error as probably occurred because you haven't got the correct
module loaded for your network card.
Debug not enabled, boot halted.
*********************************************************************
```

Now it won't boot all the way; it's stuck there. I am trying to connect to my Windows Terminal server (RDP). I suspect that there must be something missing or wrong in my build.conf file.

Comment: It looks like the driver for your network card isn't installed, and it stops there.

Comment: ..in my build.conf file i already add the LAN card driver e1000 # module

Comment: Provide more information: what is the Linux distribution? What bootloader? If you don't know, at least post the `build.conf` file you write about - can you tell, what software it belongs to?

Comment: You'll have much more luck by signing up for the official Thinstation mailing list (the general list) at http://sourceforge.net/mail/?group_id=80408 But I can tell you your thinstation.conf.buildtime is completely off.